# WordPress add_filter to post_date

Tags: filters, date, localization

I using a plugin that it makes posts and etc date to `Persian Date` but the problem is I just want to convert date in front not admin panel or etc. I found that part make this action:

```
add_filter('date_i18n', 'ztjalali_ch_date_i18n', 111, 4);
```

It using `add_filter` to do this on `date_i18n` function, can I change it somehow that convert only `date` in blog post in front. I'm not a wordpress expert and don't know too much about [date_i18n](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/), but I think it refer to all post date in everywhere, so can I change the code to only convert in front?

something like:

```
add_filter('post_date', 'ztjalali_ch_date_i18n', 111, 4);
```

I tried above but no success.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an additional filter on the frontend. Very basically it would look like this:

Frontend (eg. single.php):

`echo apply_filters( 'my_custom_persian_filter', $post_date );`

Backend (eg. functions.php)

```
function persian_date_function( $date ) {
    $date = $converted_to_persian; // there you convert date to persian
    return $date;
}
add_filter( 'my_custom_persian_filter', 'persian_date_function' );
```